# Throttling with Lodash doesn't work

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to use Lodash's `throttle` to have fewer function invokes on scroll. My code is as follows:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', _.throttle(() => { console.log('bam'); }), 1000);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work - I am getting `bam`-ed all the time, and not every one secound.

What can I do?

CodePen: http://codepen.io/tomekbuszewski/pen/oxeOXy?editors=1111

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a mistake in your code

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', _.throttle(() => { console.log('bam'); }, 1000));
```

Comment: If you generate a new function each times the event is triggered you'll not throttle your function you will just have as  many functions as without _.throttle, they'll just all be delayed...

Comment: @IlanSchemoul This code does not create a new function for each event. It generates 1 wrapped function and registers it as the handler for the event.

Answer (score 16):

The `_.throttle` function should only be generated once and not every time the event fires

```js
 var callback = _.throttle(() => { console.log('bam')}, 10000);
    window.addEventListener('scroll', callback);
```

```css
div {
 height : 100px
}
div > div {
 height : 1000px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.6.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

the `console.log("bam")` called once every 10 sec

Comment: You seem to have synthax errors in you code, and since it's my first usage of Lodash I can't seem to fix them.

Comment: Thanks, but still - your solution does generate 'bam' every scroll, not every secound.

Comment: OP's code doesn't generate a new instance of the throttled function every time, he just doesn't correctly pass the `ms` argument to throttle.

Answer (score 0):

```
var f = function() {
    console.log("bam");
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', _.throttle(f, 1000));
```

Answer (score -4):

## Simple, Efficient, And Low-Overhead Soution

You do **not** need lodash for a decent throttle function. The purpose of a throttle function is to reduce browser resources, not to apply so much overhead that you are using even more. Also, my different uses for throttle functions require many different circumstances for them. Here is my list of things that a 'good' throttle function needs that this one has.

- Minimal overhead.
- Immediate function call if it has been more than *interval* MS since the last call.
- Avoiding executing function for another *interval* MS.
- Delaying excessive event firing instead of dropping the event altogether.
- Updates the delayed event when need be so that it doesn't become 'stale'.
- Prevents the default action of the event when the throttled function is delayed.
- Be able to remove the throttle event listener listener.

And, I believe that the following throttle function satisfies all of those.

```
function throttle(func, alternateFunc, minimumInterval) {
    var executeImmediately = true, freshEvt = null;
    return function(Evt) {
        if (executeImmediately) { // Execute immediatly
            executeImmediately = false;
            setTimeout(function(f){ // handle further calls
                executeImmediately = true;
                if (freshEvt !== null) func( freshEvt );
                freshEvt = null;
            }, minimumInterval);
            return func( Evt );
        } else { // Delayed execute
            freshEvt = Evt;
            if (typeof alternateFunc === "function") alternateFunc( Evt );
        }
    };
}
```

- N.B.: `removeEventListener` can only remove the exact function passed to `addEventListener`. If you sent a wrapped function to `addEventListener`, then `removeEventListener` requires this same wrapped function, not the original function. Thus, the following does not work.

```
function clickFunctor(){ /*...*/ }

// This code throttles clickFunctor to 500ms
var throttledFunctor = throttle(clickFunctor, null, 500); // WORKS
addEventListener("click", throttledFunctor, false); // WORKS

// ONLY this removeEventListener works
removeEventListener("click", throttledFunctor, false); // WORKS

// For example, this removeEventListener does not work
removeEventListener("click", throttle(clickFunctor, null, 500), false); // FAILS
// This removeEventListener also does not work
removeEventListener("click", clickFunctor, false); // FAILS
```

If you need wrappers around `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` so that they work properly, then you can use the functions below.

```
var tfCache = []; // throttled functions cache
function listen(source, eventName, func, _opts){
    var i = 0, Len = tfCache.length, cF = null, options = _opts || {};
    a: {
        for (; i < Len; i += 4)
            if (tfCache[i] === func &&
              tfCache[i+1] === (options.ALTERNATE||null) &&
              tfCache[i+2] === (options.INTERVAL||200)
            ) break a;
        cF = throttle(func, options.ALTERNATE||null, options.INTERVAL||200);
        tfCache.push(func, options.ALTERNATE||null, options.INTERVAL||200, cF);
    }
    source.addEventListener(eventName, cF || tfCache[i+3], _opts);
    return cF === null; // return whether it used the cache or not
};
function mute(source, eventName, func, _opts){
    var options = _opts || {};
    for (var i = 0, Len = tfCache.length; i < Len; i += 4)
        if (tfCache[i] === func &&
          tfCache[i+1] === (options.ALTERNATE||null) &&
          tfCache[i+2] === (options.INTERVAL||200)
        ) {
            source.removeEventListener(eventName, tfCache[i+3], options);
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

`listen` and `mute` will work for any event on any instance that inherits from EventTarget, such as an `Element`'s `blur`/`focus`, 'click' on the `window`, `XMLHttpRequest`'s onprogress, `FileReader`'s onprogress, [etc.].

Example usage:

```js
var docElement = document.firstElementChild;
docElement.style.transition = "background .667s linear";

function whenTheDocumentScrolls() {
     var scrollTop = docElement.scrollTop || -docElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
     var bgColor = "#fff";
     
     if (scrollTop < 1600)      bgColor = "#9f9";
     else if (scrollTop < 3000)  bgColor = "#ff9";
     else if (scrollTop < 3600) bgColor = "#f9e";
     else if (scrollTop < 5600) bgColor = "#c8f751";
     else if (scrollTop < 7200) bgColor = "#68f";
     else if (scrollTop < 9200) bgColor = "#3fb";
     
     docElement.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
}
whenTheDocumentScrolls(); // Compute the background color right now

var scrollListenerOptions = {
    passive: true,
    capture: false,
    // ALTERNATE: function(){ /*...*/ },
    INTERVAL: 500 // check at most twice a second
};

function throttle(func, alternateFunc, minimumInterval) {
    var executeImmediately = true, freshEvt = null;
    return function(Evt) {
        if (executeImmediately) { // Execute immediatly
            executeImmediately = false;
            setTimeout(function(f){ // handle further calls
                executeImmediately = true;
                if (freshEvt !== null) func( freshEvt );
                freshEvt = null;
            }, minimumInterval);
            return func( Evt );
        } else { // Delayed execute
            freshEvt = Evt;
            if (typeof alternateFunc === "function") alternateFunc( Evt );
        }
    };
}

var tfCache = []; // throttled functions cache
function listen(source, eventName, func, _opts){
    var i = 0, Len = tfCache.length, cF = null, options = _opts || {};
    a: {
        for (; i < Len; i += 4)
            if (tfCache[i] === func &&
              tfCache[i+1] === (options.ALTERNATE||null) &&
              tfCache[i+2] === (options.INTERVAL||200)
            ) break a;
        cF = throttle(func, options.ALTERNATE||null, options.INTERVAL||200);
        tfCache.push(func, options.ALTERNATE||null, options.INTERVAL||200, cF);
    }
    source.addEventListener(eventName, cF || tfCache[i+3], _opts);
    return cF === null; // return whether it used the cache or not
};
function mute(source, eventName, func, _opts){
    var options = _opts || {};
    for (var i = 0, Len = tfCache.length; i < Len; i += 4)
        if (tfCache[i] === func &&
          tfCache[i+1] === (options.ALTERNATE||null) &&
          tfCache[i+2] === (options.INTERVAL||200)
        ) {
            source.removeEventListener(eventName, tfCache[i+3], _opts);
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}

listen(window, "scroll", whenTheDocumentScrolls, scrollListenerOptions);
listen(document.getElementById("stop-scrolling"), "click", function(){
    mute(window, "scroll", whenTheDocumentScrolls, scrollListenerOptions);
}, {passive: true});
```

```html
<button id="stop-scrolling" style="position:fixed;bottom:0;right:0">Remove the scroll listener</button>

<div style="font-size:1.4em;line-height:1.8;white-space:pre-wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi semper facilisis leo quis imperdiet. Maecenas vitae malesuada nibh. Donec volutpat nunc in eros pretium vulputate. Curabitur lorem ipsum, tincidunt at hendrerit sed, venenatis vitae nibh. Duis varius felis vitae sem consequat varius. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer semper eget dolor et egestas. Proin nec ipsum rhoncus, pellentesque quam non, vestibulum augue. Curabitur et diam non est tempor dignissim. Fusce tempor nisl a ligula sagittis, eget condimentum magna iaculis. Vestibulum vulputate mauris eget mi semper, eget mattis orci tincidunt. Phasellus sit amet egestas turpis. Aliquam aliquet facilisis dolor, ultrices mollis risus mollis vulputate. Praesent id ligula at mi faucibus ornare. Fusce at tristique dui. Nullam pellentesque, augue eget tristique egestas, est metus euismod odio, a convallis lacus lectus non massa.

Nullam a fringilla turpis. Mauris in ultricies est. Nam faucibus, nunc eu suscipit volutpat, est augue congue velit, fermentum ornare nibh erat ac ex. Sed ut neque auctor, facilisis arcu in, molestie leo. Praesent vestibulum lacinia sapien, ac porta ligula porttitor et. Vestibulum nec ante libero. Sed vel velit elit. Praesent tristique bibendum consectetur. Vestibulum pretium tellus sapien, eu vulputate mi condimentum ut. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;

Vestibulum semper elit risus, id fringilla enim gravida non. In in tellus quis nulla commodo volutpat. Sed tristique, magna eu sagittis porttitor, quam neque varius ante, ac mattis elit ex vitae nisl. Fusce sed justo vitae elit tempus porta. Donec nisl justo, bibendum nec dolor vitae, venenatis elementum justo. Nulla egestas quis tellus non vehicula. Proin vel lobortis felis. Quisque tempus eu elit non porta. Cras eleifend nisl nec vehicula tristique. Integer et pellentesque urna. In eu magna turpis. Vivamus vitae diam nec nulla vulputate pharetra eget vel leo. Praesent et tortor sed purus commodo finibus sit amet id ipsum. Pellentesque diam elit, condimentum et varius eu, elementum vitae quam.

Cras felis tellus, auctor non consectetur non, pharetra sed purus. In ut condimentum risus, eu ornare augue. Aliquam eu ex augue. Nunc tincidunt, libero a pellentesque dignissim, metus dui posuere mauris, eu iaculis purus dolor non quam. Donec venenatis tellus ut nisi tristique, sed egestas ipsum auctor. Integer gravida mollis nulla porta pretium. Proin vel dolor nisi. Suspendisse ut lacinia turpis. Donec lacinia lorem mollis ante pretium convallis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec vel porta libero. Donec eget arcu id risus fringilla finibus. Duis pulvinar hendrerit metus id porta. Maecenas et nulla in enim scelerisque tempus vel ut massa. Ut luctus placerat ipsum, sit amet pharetra nunc faucibus id.

Phasellus varius tortor a mi fermentum porttitor. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas mollis varius ante, non blandit ex cursus scelerisque. Vivamus sodales, diam at aliquam blandit, diam metus gravida lectus, non auctor augue felis ut justo. Proin in volutpat neque, id tempus arcu. Aenean vestibulum consequat leo, in tincidunt orci semper eu. Integer blandit vehicula consequat.

Donec accumsan purus quis sem dapibus aliquet. Etiam hendrerit sem eget tellus facilisis venenatis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vel consequat est. Sed quis convallis tellus. Vivamus quis semper odio. Mauris quis interdum ligula. Praesent cursus ante at libero sollicitudin, at varius nunc dapibus. Vivamus augue nisi, cursus in enim ut, eleifend hendrerit neque. Quisque rhoncus nibh a velit volutpat volutpat. Praesent a purus enim. Donec id fringilla nibh.

Pellentesque lectus turpis, auctor vel sem a, consequat rutrum odio. Mauris congue erat commodo, consectetur ante at, rutrum quam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ut neque vel est rutrum pellentesque. Maecenas sem est, dapibus vitae nisi non, tempor tincidunt libero. Aenean ornare auctor tellus et molestie. Phasellus vel efficitur leo. Phasellus quis venenatis lectus. Nam ac neque quis dolor tristique gravida. Fusce sem dolor, suscipit non aliquam sed, cursus faucibus turpis. Integer feugiat, nulla ut vestibulum fringilla, velit dui rhoncus quam, a ullamcorper sapien libero ut quam. Phasellus ornare posuere libero, eu venenatis nunc iaculis nec. Etiam sed malesuada ante.

Morbi consequat risus sit amet tellus lobortis convallis ut mollis arcu. Donec suscipit mollis lectus, vitae ullamcorper sem aliquam ac. Aliquam sed erat id eros malesuada aliquam. Nunc semper felis sed ligula ullamcorper congue. Ut nec cursus libero, a posuere ligula. Proin luctus laoreet mi, ac semper lectus convallis nec. Maecenas eu egestas mi. Etiam varius ex eget tincidunt auctor.

Curabitur bibendum quam id ligula lacinia, quis molestie lacus vestibulum. Etiam dapibus lacus nulla, quis luctus justo tempus sed. Praesent mi enim, efficitur quis congue vestibulum, molestie non odio. Donec nibh ex, elementum vitae sodales quis, pulvinar vitae tortor. Morbi et egestas velit, eget congue nibh. Vestibulum fringilla mi leo. Curabitur cursus viverra mauris, sed auctor odio tristique eget. Suspendisse a ipsum tellus. Etiam eleifend vel sapien non consectetur. Mauris ac felis mauris. Donec fermentum eros sit amet ex placerat, id faucibus nisl lacinia. Vivamus eget dui vitae nisl commodo feugiat vitae ac ante. Nunc ullamcorper eros id massa sagittis, ac gravida felis semper. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.

In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse potenti. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec vitae placerat ligula. Fusce malesuada mi et arcu pellentesque ornare. Fusce cursus, ipsum non gravida scelerisque, libero tortor sagittis elit, ac accumsan justo est sed ligula. Nam condimentum leo est. Vivamus hendrerit finibus metus quis cursus. Quisque consequat ipsum vitae justo volutpat ultricies. Nullam eget nisi quis sapien tempor scelerisque sit amet vel tellus. Vivamus euismod ultrices nisi a iaculis. Nam augue dui, aliquam et leo et, convallis imperdiet velit. Sed vestibulum eget quam eu fringilla. Suspendisse ac nunc ac ligula interdum congue et eget libero. In mollis dui sed mi finibus finibus.

Phasellus scelerisque, lectus in vulputate egestas, sem leo bibendum mauris, a tincidunt risus quam eu ante. Nulla placerat nibh et velit volutpat tincidunt. Ut luctus elementum massa, eget finibus tortor tincidunt at. Curabitur quis sagittis velit. Etiam finibus, quam vitae blandit vehicula, massa enim faucibus nisl, a aliquet purus justo tristique tortor. Sed fringilla tincidunt consequat. Mauris a tellus ultricies, tempus tortor nec, auctor est. Nulla feugiat nisl urna, a pulvinar erat consectetur condimentum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Quisque in ultrices mi. Donec non sapien varius, tempor quam in, semper dui. Pellentesque aliquam sapien eu quam pellentesque pretium. Cras hendrerit dolor et libero semper, eget vestibulum quam tristique. Aliquam lobortis lacus vel purus mollis maximus. Nam vel imperdiet nunc, sit amet faucibus eros. Donec viverra varius volutpat.

Sed quis mollis dolor, et posuere eros. In eu quam orci. In vitae ante sed nisl vulputate ornare. Nullam quis ipsum molestie, laoreet elit quis, commodo tellus. Donec volutpat, velit at ornare fermentum, ipsum lectus convallis nisi, sed pharetra tortor tortor eget nisl. Vestibulum porta condimentum aliquet. Cras malesuada tellus erat, id auctor lorem pulvinar sed. Etiam non arcu suscipit, interdum sem eu, dapibus est.

Pellentesque tincidunt sem varius arcu semper lacinia. Suspendisse nunc felis, aliquet vel ullamcorper vitae, malesuada at dui. Vestibulum hendrerit neque sed sodales placerat. Praesent pulvinar massa eu risus facilisis placerat. Quisque tincidunt est sed mauris placerat, id viverra risus vulputate. Aenean in iaculis justo, et suscipit ligula. Aliquam efficitur in arcu vel vehicula. Suspendisse vitae dui magna. In dictum, nibh eget eleifend fermentum, sapien ex pharetra lorem, id dignissim lectus ipsum non nibh. Praesent at dignissim orci.

Sed ante nisi, commodo et metus ac, feugiat commodo nisi. Cras ut ligula sed augue dignissim gravida ut non mauris. Nullam laoreet diam at ligula luctus finibus. Nunc porta diam sit amet pharetra lacinia. Donec luctus sodales mauris, eu bibendum nisl tempus at. Donec sed pharetra nisi. Quisque sodales ligula nec eros placerat ultricies. In sit amet scelerisque tellus, quis sollicitudin ligula. Curabitur blandit ligula non odio facilisis, vel euismod ligula tempor. Nunc ligula arcu, mollis et metus eu, ullamcorper volutpat risus. Ut sem dolor, dignissim vitae fermentum malesuada, tincidunt aliquam ex. Sed placerat diam ligula, ac vehicula nunc eleifend vel. Nulla facilisi. Mauris in lectus non tortor lacinia vestibulum ut ut turpis.

Fusce gravida massa eget tincidunt malesuada. Integer sagittis quam non augue sodales viverra. Vestibulum luctus lectus sed eros molestie, ac congue leo fermentum. Mauris id urna sagittis, accumsan urna ac, posuere neque. Etiam molestie odio lobortis purus imperdiet venenatis. Ut pretium elementum velit, quis luctus massa sodales eu. Suspendisse varius at velit suscipit maximus. Pellentesque gravida ante a vehicula faucibus. Proin tincidunt scelerisque vestibulum.

Pellentesque varius semper metus, dignissim maximus elit hendrerit vel. Donec lobortis, tellus nec dictum pellentesque, nisl nisl ullamcorper erat, sit amet interdum nunc est sit amet lacus. In varius varius turpis vel facilisis. Vivamus ac viverra sem, vel scelerisque felis. Etiam eget nunc in nibh tempor dictum. Pellentesque dapibus auctor ante nec sollicitudin. Integer auctor mi tristique lectus convallis pretium. Cras aliquam, massa tempus molestie viverra, massa orci interdum ex, et dapibus justo massa eu arcu. Sed elementum pulvinar turpis, sed congue lorem tincidunt et.

Nam egestas felis orci, facilisis auctor urna sollicitudin ac. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Duis non euismod arcu. Aenean rhoncus ipsum ut neque finibus, ut pharetra dolor maximus. Pellentesque quam est, vestibulum non mattis id, luctus ut enim. Nam tempor lacus ut suscipit sagittis. Sed egestas id nisi quis tempus. Aenean non cursus quam, nec dignissim augue. Curabitur in placerat quam, in aliquet dui. Curabitur egestas, arcu nec auctor tempor, nibh lectus sollicitudin ligula, a malesuada mauris eros in orci. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

Donec varius consequat dolor in pretium. Sed molestie tempor lectus. Curabitur consequat tristique risus, ac tempor ligula tristique ac. Cras porta blandit pretium. Donec vel enim nunc. Pellentesque quis bibendum dui, ac gravida orci. Donec sollicitudin massa in leo iaculis consequat.

Nulla at libero ullamcorper turpis venenatis interdum. Pellentesque gravida ante at nisl dignissim, vel consequat leo bibendum. Curabitur id turpis libero. Phasellus nec sapien magna. Quisque rhoncus sem in vulputate tempus. Nullam gravida eget purus ut imperdiet. Curabitur bibendum dapibus magna id ultricies. Sed vestibulum volutpat ante, sed porttitor ante porta in. Sed vitae eros dui. Sed sit amet nunc odio.

In cursus, est vitae fermentum facilisis, sapien felis accumsan erat, eu pretium ligula neque at orci. Cras at lorem sit amet enim finibus hendrerit ac lobortis est. Aenean nec dictum nulla. Vivamus scelerisque porttitor nisi, quis bibendum massa commodo et. Fusce nec dapibus purus, vitae sagittis nisl. Vivamus consectetur orci rutrum orci aliquam viverra. Morbi sodales elit at gravida imperdiet. Pellentesque sit amet felis sit amet orci venenatis gravida. Phasellus iaculis augue vitae laoreet lobortis.

Maecenas bibendum ultrices gravida. In eu tincidunt libero, quis tempus velit. Suspendisse placerat nisl magna, eu fringilla nunc luctus malesuada. Vestibulum sit amet orci hendrerit tortor pharetra lobortis ut at lacus. Cras erat metus, pretium sed metus ut, interdum posuere nisi. Nullam dolor sem, facilisis sed ex at, feugiat gravida lacus. Sed pellentesque mauris arcu, sit amet finibus nisi pulvinar non. Praesent metus felis, viverra quis libero in, sagittis vehicula ex. Phasellus a consectetur eros. Sed consectetur interdum sollicitudin. Donec sollicitudin venenatis arcu ultrices vehicula. Maecenas dolor urna, placerat id justo at, laoreet maximus enim. Integer porta odio ut purus interdum, at malesuada nisi tempus. Nullam vel cursus nulla. Mauris vehicula gravida sem. Nulla facilisi.

Etiam quis nisi at nibh varius tempor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Vivamus venenatis massa laoreet varius blandit. Etiam gravida elit in pulvinar tincidunt. Donec rutrum neque in consectetur dignissim. Vestibulum nec lorem sed augue pretium fermentum. Morbi mattis libero purus, eget accumsan massa accumsan vel.

Nunc ullamcorper massa augue, nec bibendum metus fringilla suscipit. Donec iaculis non nulla eu sodales. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nam dapibus justo odio, at mollis nulla mollis dignissim. Suspendisse mollis, purus sed accumsan tristique, ex quam accumsan mauris, vitae tincidunt turpis magna in quam. Duis vel iaculis nibh. Praesent imperdiet diam at felis cursus commodo. Vestibulum sodales dapibus lacinia. Cras vitae eros ultricies, posuere purus eget, varius arcu. Nulla sodales mauris imperdiet dui bibendum, eu egestas lacus porttitor. Vivamus urna dolor, fermentum sit amet odio id, pharetra venenatis risus. Nunc id tortor metus. Quisque ultrices laoreet ante, a commodo libero dignissim gravida.

Sed bibendum ultricies rutrum. Aliquam ornare lacinia commodo. In dapibus nulla id fringilla convallis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Etiam mattis laoreet interdum. Proin id nibh purus. Aenean nisi dui, imperdiet id lobortis vel, faucibus aliquam dui. Nulla maximus, nisi vitae egestas ornare, sem leo feugiat augue, ut tristique magna odio ut mauris. Ut finibus massa ut ex luctus, at commodo turpis efficitur. Maecenas vestibulum est ac lobortis vehicula. Curabitur sit amet pellentesque turpis. Integer rhoncus eget urna vel mollis. Morbi quis orci accumsan, fermentum augue in, condimentum lacus.

Pellentesque quis augue urna. In facilisis, est sollicitudin feugiat suscipit, dui ipsum ullamcorper mauris, sed ultrices ligula mauris ut urna. Maecenas posuere varius consectetur. Nunc sed egestas metus, eu imperdiet neque. Suspendisse sit amet urna et dui rhoncus vestibulum sit amet facilisis eros. Cras molestie euismod nisl, sit amet vehicula tortor efficitur egestas. Nullam ac facilisis urna. Nunc tempor felis sed ipsum feugiat hendrerit. Vestibulum sed lobortis nisi. Proin laoreet tempus tempor. Ut sed hendrerit ante, sed interdum urna. Aliquam tempus eros vitae dictum vehicula. Vestibulum purus quam, elementum sit amet rutrum in, dapibus nec metus. Quisque in mollis dui. Sed malesuada posuere sem ac gravida.</div>
```

Unfortunately, Stackoverflow disables code snippets on poorly misjudged and underappreciated answers, so [here is a jsfiddle link to run the code instead.](https://jsfiddle.net/sq0oyLaj/)

Try scrolling down through the page in the demo and observing how the background color changes as you scroll. Try using your cursor to move the scrollbar up and down rapidly to see if you can get it to break and fail to update the colors. It will not break because this is a sturdy solid throttling function. Once you find a color that you like, click the "Remove the scroll listener" button in order to stop changing colors.

Although changing the background color with scrolling is a bit impractical (on a real website, it would simply distract the user from the content), I hope that this demonstration serves to show how powerful a good throttle function can be in terms of performance and fluid user experience.

### Comparison To Lodash

Observe the following Lodash implementation of a throttled function.

```
/**
 * lodash (Custom Build) <https://lodash.com/>
 * Build: `lodash modularize exports="npm" -o ./`
 * Copyright jQuery Foundation and other contributors <https://jquery.org/>
 * Released under MIT license <https://lodash.com/license>
 * Based on Underscore.js 1.8.3 <http://underscorejs.org/LICENSE>
 * Copyright Jeremy Ashkenas, DocumentCloud and Investigative Reporters & Editors
 */
/** Used as the `TypeError` message for "Functions" methods. */
var FUNC_ERROR_TEXT = 'Expected a function';
/** Used as references for various `Number` constants. */
var NAN = 0 / 0;
/** `Object#toString` result references. */
var symbolTag = '[object Symbol]';
/** Used to match leading and trailing whitespace. */
var reTrim = /^\s+|\s+$/g;
/** Used to detect bad signed hexadecimal string values. */
var reIsBadHex = /^[-+]0x[0-9a-f]+$/i;
/** Used to detect binary string values. */
var reIsBinary = /^0b[01]+$/i;
/** Used to detect octal string values. */
var reIsOctal = /^0o[0-7]+$/i;
/** Built-in method references without a dependency on `root`. */
var freeParseInt = parseInt;
/** Detect free variable `global` from Node.js. */
var freeGlobal = typeof global == 'object' && global && global.Object === Object && global;
/** Detect free variable `self`. */
var freeSelf = typeof self == 'object' && self && self.Object === Object && self;
/** Used as a reference to the global object. */
var root = freeGlobal || freeSelf || Function('return this')();
/** Used for built-in method references. */
var objectProto = Object.prototype;
/**
 * Used to resolve the
//// Continued at https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash.throttle@4.1.1/index.js /////
```

Granted, the reason for why it is so big is because of all of the comments. Thus, let us compare the minified sizes:

```
// Lodash implementation: 1805 bytes (+GZip => 872 bytes);
//    19 suspended variables per throttle
throttle=function(){function A(a,b,c){function d(b){var p=g,c=k;g=k=void 0;l=b;return m=a.apply(c,p)}function h(a){var p=a-f;a-=l;return void 0===f||p>=b||0>p||q&&a>=u}function r(){var a=v.Date.now();if(h(a))return n(a);var c=setTimeout;var d=a-l;a=b-(a-f);d=q?B(a,u-d):a;e=c(r,d)}function n(a){e=void 0;if(w&&g)return d(a);g=k=void 0;return m}function x(){var a=v.Date.now(),c=h(a);g=arguments;k=this;f=a;if(c){if(void 0===e)return l=a=f,e=setTimeout(r,b),y?d(a):m;if(q)return e=setTimeout(r,b),d(f)}void 0===
e&&(e=setTimeout(r,b));return m}var g,k,m,e,f,l=0,y=!1,q=!1,w=!0;if("function"!=typeof a)throw new TypeError("Expected a function");b=z(b)||0;if(t(c)){y=!!c.leading;var u=(q="maxWait"in c)?C(z(c.maxWait)||0,b):u;w="trailing"in c?!!c.trailing:w}x.cancel=function(){void 0!==e&&clearTimeout(e);l=0;g=f=k=e=void 0};x.flush=function(){return void 0===e?m:n(v.Date.now())};return x}function t(a){var b=typeof a;return!!a&&("object"==b||"function"==b)}function z(a){if("number"==typeof a)return a;var b=a;if("symbol"==
typeof b||b&&"object"==typeof b&&"[object Symbol]"==D.call(b))return n;t(a)&&(a="function"==typeof a.valueOf?a.valueOf():a,a=t(a)?a+"":a);if("string"!=typeof a)return 0===a?a:+a;a=a.replace(E,"");return(b=F.test(a))||G.test(a)?H(a.slice(2),b?2:8):I.test(a)?n:+a}var n=0/0,E=/^\s+|\s+$/g,I=/^[-+]0x[0-9a-f]+$/i,F=/^0b[01]+$/i,G=/^0o[0-7]+$/i,H=parseInt,J="object"==typeof self&&self&&self.Object===Object&&self,v="object"==typeof global&&global&&global.Object===Object&&global||J||Function("return this")(),
D=Object.prototype.toString,C=Math.max,B=Math.min;return function(a,b,c){var d=!0,h=!0;if("function"!=typeof a)throw new TypeError("Expected a function");t(c)&&(d="leading"in c?!!c.leading:d,h="trailing"in c?!!c.trailing:h);return A(a,b,{leading:d,maxWait:b,trailing:h})}}()
```

But, what if we took all of that functionality in Lodash, stripped out the `.cancel` method (replacing it with `mute`/`listen`), made the `leading` options no longer an option, instead always true, and removed all of the fuss over typecasting under the assumption that you are conscious of which types you are using? The result is a radically debloated, much more performance, and just as useable throttling function that is my solution. Further, if you have special needs for a throttling function, then my solution is easily extendable with an optional 2nd parameter that defines a function to be called when an invocation to the main throttled function is dropped due to throttling.

```
// My implementation: 170 bytes (+GZip => 143 bytes);
//    5 suspended variables per throttle
function throttle(d,e,f){var c=!0,a=null;return function(b){if(c)return c=!1,setTimeout(function(b){c=!0;null!==a&&d(a);a=null},f),d(b);a=b;"function"===typeof e&&e(b)}};
```

The `listen`/`mute` are extra convenience methods that keep track of the throttle reference for you so that you do not have to. The minified Lodash code does not include these extra convenience, so why should my code have to be compared with conveniences to Lodash which is without conveniences? Thus, my above code snippet only represents my throttler without the `listen`/`mute` convenience methods.

Thus, I rest my case that my implementation is comparable to Lodash in functionality and far superior to Lodash in size and performa

Comment: @downvoter why the downvote? Is this solution not more practical and performant than Lodash's solution?

Comment: I'm amazed. Is this actual JavaScript ? what is ~( and why "-1" ? I don't even know what to say ... even if it JS it is using some black magic it is incredibly painful to read, doesn't answer the specific question about lodash. MORE importantly if you think using a library like lodash or any code not made by you is "overhead" you don't understand coding. You SHOULD use well used packages instead of recreating exact same features.

Comment: @IlanSchemoul Yes, you are correct that the old function above before my revisions was difficult to read. However, I would argue that the new function above answers the question being asked exactly and is perfect for throttling scrolling. Also, I added the Lodash implementation just to prove to you definitively that there is way too much unnecessary overhead garbage in some of these libraries like Lodash. Nevertheless, you are correct that I would love to use packages if only their creators could share my performance/size concerns. However, this is rarely (if ever) the case.

Comment: Then why you don't just make a package pushing people to replace a well known, peer reviewed, tested module by an huge function they'd copy paste from here is anti pattern. Make a package and make benchmarks if you really think you can make a change but micro optimization is not worth it usually on the web. It really is not.

Comment: @IlanSchemoul Thank you for your comment and your insights.